# how to move the image with in screen boundary

Tags: android

i have problem with moving image when i move image it goes outside the screen 
   i want to move move within boundary of screen size 
how to fix it 
Here is the touch listner code for that image.

```
private ImageView nail_cleaner;
RelativeLayout re_layout;

PointF DownPT = null; 
PointF StartPT = null;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    startMoving(nail_cleaner, event);
    return true;
}

public void startMoving(ImageView img, MotionEvent event) {
    int eid = event.getAction();
    switch (eid) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        PointF mv = new PointF(event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY()
                - DownPT.y);
        img.setX((int) (StartPT.x + mv.x));
        img.setY((int) (StartPT.y + mv.y));
        StartPT = new PointF(img.getX(), img.getY());
        if (event.getX() == event.getX()) {

        }

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        DownPT.x = event.getX();
        DownPT.y = event.getY();
        StartPT = new PointF(img.getX(), img.getY());
        Log.e("get points : ", img.getX() + "" + img.getY());
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.clean_wash);

    re_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_clean);
    nail_cleaner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id_nail_cleaner);

    DownPT = new PointF();
    StartPT = new PointF(); 
    nail_cleaner.setOnTouchListener(this);



}
```

and also if i move the image it moves back to the other image, i want to move this image in front of the other ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

    PointF mv = new PointF(event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY()
            - DownPT.y);
int imgWidth = img.getWidth()/2;
int imgHeight = img.getHeight()/2;
if(StartPT.x + mv.x + imgWidth > 0 && StartPT.x + mv.x + imgWidth < ScreenWidth){
        img.setX((int) (StartPT.x + mv.x));}
if(StartPT.y + mv.y + imgHeight > 0 && StartPT.y + mv.y + imgHeight < ScreenHeight){
        img.setY((int) (StartPT.y + mv.y));}
        StartPT = new PointF(img.getX(), img.getY());


    break;
```

Something like this you have to do

Answer (score -1):

Set the screen boundary based on the screen size and then check each wall for example with the left wall `if(img.getX() <= 0) 
    img.setX(0);`

Answer (score -1):

please see i am update your answer in one please only

```
private ImageView nail_cleaner;
RelativeLayout re_layout;

PointF DownPT = null; 
PointF StartPT = null;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    startMoving(nail_cleaner, event);
    return true;
}

public void startMoving(ImageView img, MotionEvent event) {
    int eid = event.getAction();

     //Get the device height and width

     DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
     int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
     int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;


    switch (eid) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

    /*Check the current x position is less than width of device if get true then move   the object */
         if(event.getX() < (wwidth-10)){ 
              PointF mv = new PointF(event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY()
                - DownPT.y);
              img.setX((int) (StartPT.x + mv.x));
              img.setY((int) (StartPT.y + mv.y));
              StartPT = new PointF(img.getX(), img.getY());
        }



        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        DownPT.x = event.getX();
        DownPT.y = event.getY();
        StartPT = new PointF(img.getX(), img.getY());
        Log.e("get points : ", img.getX() + "" + img.getY());
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.clean_wash);

    re_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_clean);
    nail_cleaner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id_nail_cleaner);

    DownPT = new PointF();
    StartPT = new PointF(); 
    nail_cleaner.setOnTouchListener(this);



}
```